# Plot a EPSG:4326 KML File using Google Maps V3

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, kml

I have a KML file that uses EPSG:4326.
Is there any way to plot this onto a Google Map (v3) which uses Mercator?

[Here is the page I am working on](http://www.winelisthq.com/maptest.php)

The district data comes from one source and is Google friendly.

The outage data is generated by the power company using their GIS system. It shows a list of power outages. However nothing is shown on the map.
Have seen this file work in openlayers but I really have no clue why it would not be showing up.

Comment: http://winelisthq.com/outages.kml is a 404 for me.

Comment: Is the MIME types set for this webserver? Google Earth reads KML and KMZ files. The MIME type for KML files is

    * application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml

The MIME type for KMZ files is
    * application/vnd.google-earth.kmz
For Apache, add these lines to the httpd.conf file:
    * AddType application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml .kml
    * AddType application/vnd.google-earth.kmz .kmz

Answer (score 3):

Does the file display correctly (in the right location) in Google Earth?
If so it will be okay to overlay in Google Maps API.

Comment: I have tried to plot this in Google Maps and it does not display at all. Plotting a single point from this file puts me in Antarctica :S

Answer (score 2):

Edit:  reproject it to wgs84. You can do this with [ogr2ogr using the -t_srs switch](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).

Once it is in wgs84/EPSG 4326. Take a look at this example:  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml.html

The [.kml file used there](https://web.archive.org/web/20160505162859/http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com:80/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml) is in lat, lng and plots without issue.

Comment: This is in Mercator format though. The file I have is not in that same standard Google Maps format though. Which is quite inconvenient. OpenLayers supports different projections but I am not sure how this is achieved in native GoogleMaps.

Comment: EPSG 4326 is a lat, lng based coordinate system, see:  http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/. If your .kml is actually in web mercator, you'll need to reproject it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you get this kml file? I don't think I've ever dealt with any kml that wasn't in lat, lng.

Comment: Hi Swingley, I think you caught an error there. I am not exactly sure which system google uses. But I have no clues as to what is generating the file or how to make it project properly :(
Linked the a sample page if that helps. Thank you!

Comment: @aaronfarr, can you post a sample coordinate from the outages file? Plus, what city/county/etc. should the data be in?

Answer (score 0):

Try this site and see if the KML/KMZ file is loaded properly.  Our KML/KMZ files always had to be in WGS84 EPSG:4326.  The other alternative is to use Google Earth to load the file.  If you can't load it in Google Earth, then the KML/KMZ file is corrupt.

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/layers/layers.html